# Thymeleaf: Building variable names dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to build the name of a var dynamically by concatenating the value of a variable and adding some string afterwards, as I add these variable in runtime. Something like the following should work but it does not.

```
th:text="${__#{myClass.getA().getB()}+'-result'__}"
```

Is this even possible to do? I dont know the name of the variable, I can only construct it like this unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, Thymeleaf supports expression preprocessing:

Let's start with some examples:
The message(i18n) expressions should be referenced using the # character. So let's suppose you have the message.key in your translation file. To reference it in Thymeleaf you will have to use

```
th:text="#{message.key}"
```

In your scenario your key name is generated dynamically based on a variable so for preprocessing it in thymeleaf you need to use two underscores __

Let's suppose in your context you have a model variable called myModelVariable with a method messagePrefix(). Our example becomes:

```
th:text="#{__${myModelVariable.messagePrefix()}__}"
```

This means the myModelVariable.messagePrefix() will be processed first and the result will be used as the key name which will be then resolved to a nice user friendly message.

And if you also want to add a static part at the end of it will look like this:

```
th:text="#{__${myModelVariable.messagePrefix()}__}+'*'"
```

Even the key can contain a static part so this is also accepted:

```
th:text="#{__${myModelVariable.messagePrefix()}__.staticsuffix}+'*'"
```

More info you can find in the section 2.7 here:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html